# Why does pandas convert the dtype of a column from object to float when I apply str.upper()?

Tags: python, pandas

I load a csv file into a dataframe, specifying the dtype for the columns:

```
mycols = {..., 'somecolumn': object, ...}
df = pd.read_csv(..., usecols=mycols.keys(), dtype=mycols, ...)
```

There is no data in somecolumn (i.e. it only contains nans), but the dtype is object after loading. Now, when I do:

```
df['somecolumn'] = df['somecolumn'].str.upper()
```

pandas converts the dtype from object to float. Why?

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: @jezrael: It is 0.18

Answer (score 0):

It is bug.

Reason is `NaN`s are float, so if only missing values dtypes is changed.

You can upgrade pandas for avoid this problem:

```
from io import StringIO

temp="""ID,a,somecolumn
1,s,
2,f"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
mycols = {'somecolumn': object}
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), dtype=mycols)

print (df)
   ID  a somecolumn
0   1  s        NaN
1   2  f        NaN

print (df.dtypes)
ID             int64
a             object
somecolumn    object
dtype: object

print (df.somecolumn.apply(type))
0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
Name: somecolumn, dtype: object
```

Comment: What does `df.somecolumn.apply(type)` do?

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers - Only test type if float, it means `NaN`s are not strings `NaN`, but missing values